# How to auto refresh data in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, spotify

making a basic spotify app using react for the first time. 
currenty the "Now playing" feature is using a button to display what is being played by the user.
How can I change this command so it does it in real time?

currently looks like this..

```
<button onClick={() => this.getNowPlaying()}>
   Check Now Playing
 </button>
```

any help would be great :)

Comment: Semi-unrelated, you can change `() => this.getNowPlaying()` to `this.getNowPlaying` since you are passing it no parameters

Comment: In order to do something like this you'll need to use some sort of a web socket (so that you don't have to 'refresh' to get what is 'now' playing).. It looks like Spotify puts out an SDK, called the [Web Playback SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/), that appears to wrap around some sort of socket/webhook type of API. [You can listen for events](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/reference/#event-player-state-changed) then *react* to them as necessary.

Comment: If you don't want to use socket or something similar, you could create a setInterval on component mount that calls this.getNowPlaying each N seconds and store request response in a state

Comment: Hey, Im TheOP, this is currently beyond my scope of knowledge. If any of you guys dont mind looking, ive posted again but with the full example code if you want to have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60515750/how-to-auto-refresh-data-in-real-time-react